# Ruby equivalent for python array

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I need a ruby equivalent for the following python code

```
import array
my_array = array.array('B', [0x00, 0x04, 0xcc, 0x50]).tostring()
```

**UPDATE:** I am trying to write 4 bytes to the serial port using ruby-serialport gem.

I was able to make it work in python by writing the above byte array to the serial port. Now I am trying to do the same in ruby.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Did you try `['B', [0x00, 0x04, 0xcc, 0x50]].to_s`?

Comment: I am trying to send an array of 4 bytes to the serial port

Comment: You really need to beef up the question or else nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206)?

```
byte_string = [0x00, 0x04, 0xCC, 0x50].pack('C*')
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206):

> `arr.pack ( aTemplateString ) → aBinaryString`
>   Packs the contents of *arr* into a binary sequence according to the directives in *aTemplateString*.

The `C` template is for unsigned eight bit integers (i.e. single bytes) and the `*` just means "use the preceding template for the rest of the elements in the array".

Comment: Thanks mu, It helped me solved the issue. I have green signal and have given an upvote

Comment: @Billy: The reverse is [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112) in case you need to read some bytes from the port and turn them into useful numbers and the like.

Comment: Hi mu, thanks again... The above comment helped me to read the data from the port.

Answer (score 1):

You can put bytes, which are given in hexadecimal, directly into your string. Below piece is valid for both Python and Ruby.

```
"\x00\x04\xcc\x50"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to get the following string: `\x00\x04\xccP`. You can simply write `"\x00\x04\xcc\x50"`